# How to search for <p> by id for condition in Javascript, and then output text in another <p>?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

Sorry, I tried to search for an answer, but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I am trying to make and webpage using Javascript, and I need some sort of decoder. For example, I have one abbreviation which is "NN", which stands for "Noun Nominative". Another abbreviation is "NA" which stands for "Noun Accusative". Another is "AN" which is "Adjective Nominative". There are many (too many) mixed-and-matched instances of these abbreviations, so I am trying to make a easy way for my Javascript/HTML code to search the whole page for every instance of "N" when it is the part of speech, and then output "Noun" in a different `<p>` when the abbreviation containing "N" is clicked. I hope this makes sense. So I came up with this:

```js
document.querySelector("div.abbreviation").onclick = parseWord;
function parseWord(event) {
  if (event.target.id === 'noun') {
    document.getElementById("part-of-speech-decoded").innerHTML = "Noun";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="abbreviation">
  <p id="noun">N</p>
  <p id="nominative">N</p>
</div>
<div id="decoder">
  <p id="part-of-speech-decoded"></p>
  <p id="case-decoded"></p>
</div>
```

Obviously, it is not correct by a long shot and the formatting is terrible (I am very new to coding), but I hope you can see what I am trying to do. So I want my function to search if p id = "noun", then when the div containing p id="noun" is clicked, I want the word "Noun" to show up in where p id="part-of-speech-decoded" is.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Define the onclick on that element then.

Comment: decodeWord() method is missing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.target.id` and capitalise the first letter:

```js
document.querySelector("div.abbreviation").onclick = parseWord;
function parseWord(event) {
  var word = event.target.id.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + event.target.id.slice(1);
  document.getElementById("part-of-speech-decoded").innerHTML = word;
}
```

```html
<div class="abbreviation">
  <p id="noun">N</p>
  <p id="nominative">N</p>
</div>
<p id="part-of-speech-decoded"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of creation options Object with 'id' and its value to be displayed

```js
document.querySelector("div.abbreviation").onclick = parseWord;
let abbrArr = {
  'noun' : 'Noun',
  'nominative' : 'Nominative',
  'nn':'Noun Nominative',
  'na':'Noun Accusative',
  
}
function parseWord(event) {
    document.getElementById("part-of-speech-decoded").innerHTML = abbrArr[event.target.id];
}
```

```html
<html>

     <body>
    <div class="abbreviation" onclick="parseWord(this)">
    <p id="noun">N</p>
    <p id="nominative">N</p>
    <p id="nn">NN</p>
    <p id="na">NA</p>
    </div>

    <div id="decoder">
    <p id="part-of-speech-decoded"></p>
    <p id="case-decoded"></p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jJvxpY?editors=1010